# How can I make OkHttp get a parameter out of Jersey and use in Interceptor?

Tags: jersey, retrofit, retrofit2, dropwizard, okhttp

Using Dropwizard+Jersey for a web application that a user logs in with their username/password and a cookie with their user-id is created. They send back this user-id cookie with each request.

I can get this cookie just fine in Jersey. The problem is when I want to involve Retrofit2 and OkHttp.

```java
public interface Interceptor {
  Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException;

  interface Chain {
    Request request();

    Response proceed(Request request) throws IOException;

    /**
     * Returns the connection the request will be executed on. This is only available in the chains
     * of network interceptors; for application interceptors this is always null.
     */
    @Nullable Connection connection();
  }
}
```

So that `Request` need to contains `User-Id`
now the problem is, how do we make OkHttp get this User-Id out of Jersey?

We need to synchronize it when we send to RequestInterceptor.
I don't see an easy way to inject things into RequestInterceptor
because it's Okhttp. The problem is Jersey are Java 1900-2000 where Retrofit and OkHttp are like Java 2015+

So the only way to do that `User-Id` in one place is using `RequestInterceptor`
It's an interface and it must be shared so User-Id must somehome come from `parameter` inside `intercept` function not from constructor.
That parameter needs to have `User-Id` so we don't have to do nasty things like ThreadLocal, or synchronize.

UPDATE: I made a samle project:

https://github.com/andrewarrow/web-wash

If you look at this file:

https://github.com/andrewarrow/web-wash/blob/master/src/team/higher/web/resource/DashboardResource.kt

The goal is to be able to replace:

```java
userClient.getSomething(user_id)
```

with

```java
userClient.getSomething()
```

and have the userClient auto-magically get the user_id in a thread
safe way. And keep in mind:

https://github.com/andrewarrow/web-wash/blob/master/src/team/higher/web/client/UserClient.kt

```kotlin
@GET("user/test")
fun getSomething(@Header("User-Id") id: String): String
```

will use the id in @Header that causes OKHttp and Retrofit2 to make a
URL connection and place that id in the http header of that http GET
to the api:

https://api.github.com/user/test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> User-Id must somehome come from parameter inside intercept function not from constructor. That parameter needs to have User-Id so we don't have to do nasty things like ThreadLocal, or synchronize.

There's a little workaround for this using proxies. With Jersey, what you can do is create a small wrapper for the user id, and then let Jersey proxy it. We can do that with a `javax.inject.Provider` to lazily retrieve the user in the interceptor. When we do this, the user will be tied to the context of the request (this is guaranteed, we don't need to worry about managing our own ThreadLocals or anything).

```java
public class UserIdInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final Provider<User> userProvider;

    UserIdInterceptor(Provider<User> userProvider) {
        this.userProvider = userProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        final User user = userProvider.get();
        if (user.isValid()) {
            return chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("User-Id", userProvider.get().getName())
                    .build());
        } else {
            return chain.proceed(chain.request());
        }
    }
}
```

What we will do is use a Jersey `Factory` to create the `User` in a request scope. This way we will be able to create a new user with the cookie for each request.

```java
public class UserFactory implements Factory<User> {

    @Inject
    private Provider<ContainerRequest> request;

    @Override
    public User provide() {
        Cookie cookie = request.get().getCookies().get("User-Id");
        return cookie != null
                ? new User(cookie.getValue())
                : new User(null);
    }
}
```

What we'll do is also create a factory for `Retrofit`. That way we can inject the `Provider<User>` into the factory and pass it to the interceptor when we construct it.

```java
public class RetrofitFactory implements Factory<Retrofit> {

    private final Retrofit retrofit;

    @Inject
    private RetrofitFactory(Provider<User> userProvider,
                            BaseUrlProvider urlProvider) {

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new UserIdInterceptor(userProvider))
                .build();

        this.retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(urlProvider.baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public Retrofit provide() {
        return this.retrofit;
    }
}
```

And then bind it all together in an `AbstractBinder`

```java
@Override
public void configure() {
    bindFactory(RetrofitFactory.class)
            .to(Retrofit.class)
            .in(Singleton.class);

    bindFactory(UserFactory.class)
            .to(User.class)
            .in(RequestScoped.class)
            .proxy(true);

    bindFactory(ClientFactories.MessageClientFactory.class)
            .to(MessageClient.class);

    bind(new BaseUrlProvider(this.baseUrl))
            .to(BaseUrlProvider.class);
}
```

I put together a complete demo in this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-okhttp-interceptor-demo)